# Process.Start returns Nothing when opening up PDF with Microsoft Edge

Tags: .net, process, microsoft-edge

Up to now, PDFs were opened by Acrobat Reader.
When I did this...

```
Dim iProcIDPDF As Integer = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PATH_TO_PDF_FILE).Id
```

... all was fine, I got the process ID.

Now I let Microsoft Edge open up the PDF for me with the same code, the PDF is opened up, but I get the error "System.NullReferenceException: Object wasn't set to any instance. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...) returned Nothing."

This also gives the same error:

```
Dim iProcIDPDF As Integer = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:" & PATH_TO_PDF_FILE).Id
```

How could I get the process ID of Edge?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `processid` of Microsoft Edge is the `processid` of the application managing Edge's tabs as each tab is a process and you won't get that value using Process.Start(). You will have to check how to get the processes from a HostedApplication as Edge is a modern app.

If Internet Explorer is the one showing the PDF you will not be able to get the process showing it, is that simple (in case it matters).

Answer (score 0):

See the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName) documentation for the return value:

> A new Process that is associated with the process resource, or null if
>   no process resource is started.

In your case you get a null return value (and since don't test for this and reference the Id property you get the 'Object wasn't set to any instance' error). You likely get a null value since Edge was already running and hence no new process was started.

To retrieve the Process Id for a running process you might want to use  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName.